# Frequency extracted from MATLAB's $\tt fft$ is not very accurate

Tags: matlab, fft, signal-analysis, dft, frequency

As a test I made up a sine wave in MATLAB of this form

```
y = 5*sin((2 * pi * freq).*x + 1.4) - 6;
```

where `freq` is `10` and `x` varies from $0$ to $1.5$ with a resolution of `1/1000` as shown below

```
fs = 1000;
x = 0:1/fs: 1.5 - (1/fs);
```

So I already know the frequency to be able to verify it with `fft`. After computing the amplitude FFT `abs(fft(yy))`, I find that the frequency bin with the highest magnitude is $16$. Since I have $1500$ samples which correspond to a sampling frequency of $1000$ then the 16$^\rm{th}$ bin corresponds to

$$\mathrm{\frac{Frequency \ Bin \times Sampling \ Frequency}{Number \ of\ Samples} = \frac{16 \times 1000}{1500} = 10.6667\ Hz}$$

However I know that my frequency I hardcoded is actually $10\ \rm Hz$. This can be repeated with different values and the same inaccurate result keeps occurring. And the smaller the hardcoded frequency the  larger the error in the result. Why is this happening?

Comment: The frequency resolution is given by `sampling frequency/fft length` so in order to get better accuracy increase the fft length. If you can't do that (not enough samples), then you'll have to settle for what you already have.

Comment: @dsp_user, This is not true at all!  For a single pure tone in a DFT, the frequency (and phase and magnitude) can be found *exactly*.  This is the main topic of my blog articles.  Yes, I discovered all the formulas I present.  The link to my blog is on my profile page.

Comment: @CedronDawg Can you find the frequency exactly even if it is not periodic in the DFT aperture (i.e. if the DFT doesn't consist of just deltas)?

Comment: How is this not true? What if the sampling frequency were, say, `4kHz`? You woudn't be able to get the exact frequency then, would you (`4bin*4000/1500 = 10.67`)?.

Comment: @Tendero, Yes, for complex or real tones.  I have several formulas for each.  The results are exact for a single noiseless tone.  The different formulas vary in their robustness in the presence of noise/other tones.  I also have a corrected version of McLeod's estimator in the pipeline.  I really recommend you read all my blog articles in order.

Comment: @dsp_user, I can and do.  See the numerical example in https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/773.php.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you try to get an independent verification of your formulas? I'll try your test code when I find the time.

Comment: @dsp_user, Let's see.  The derivations are mathematical proofs and the examples are numerical validation.  I discovered the early formulas about ten years ago and sent them to professors and experts in the field.  The most common reply I got was "Not my specialty", despite most of them teaching courses in the area.  The refusal of acceptance, as echoed by your attitude, has been mind blowing to me.  The blog article I referenced has been up for 3 years and has more than 1000 page hits.  It has neither been refuted nor gone viral.  The blog is on a DSP specific site.

Comment: I'm not well-versed in math to validate your formulas but I can try your code. Patience :)

Comment: @dsp_user, Take all the time you want.  The math is surprisingly simple, nothing beyond the definitions and ordinary algebra.  No calculus or reliance on the continuous case whatsoever.  I do use some Linear Algebra later on.  The first article is about Euler's equation and the Unit Circle, I recommend starting there.

Comment: Sinc/Dirichlet interpolation methods also work for precise frequency estimation of non-integer-periodic-in-aperture (non-FFT-bin-centered) sinusoids.

Comment: remember MATLAB hasn't acknowledged the wisdom of [Edsger Dijkstra](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html).  you will have [Off-by-one errors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) using MATLAB.

Comment: @ hotpaw2, Precise is not the same as exact.  The sinc function pertains to the continuous FT.  The Dirichlet kernel pertains to a single complex tone.  Since real tones are really the sum of two complex tones, it does not apply.  My frequency formulas for complex tones are based on bin value equations which are in essence a different form of the the Dirichlet kernel.  Those equations, their derivation, and an explanation showing the sinc function is the limit of the Dirichlet kernel can be found here:
https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/1038.php

Comment: @dsp_user, Check out this article (http://www.tsdconseil.fr/log/scriptscilab/festim/freqestim-comp.pdf) for an independent assessment of my formulas compared with others.  Candan's second formula from his paper "Analysis and Further Improvement of Fine Resolution Frequency Estimation Method From Three DFT Samples" (2013) for complex tones is also exact.  It is also mathematically equivalent to my 3 bin complex tone formula given in the comparison paper, though I didn't know it at the time.  To my knowledge, Candan is the first person to find an exact formula after I found mine (2008).

Comment: Pretty interesting stuff. I can see that you also derived a formula for DFT bin value computations which has a `O(N)` complexity. However, since you do need to know the frequency, amplitude and phase (of a pure tone) in advance, this doesn't seem to be useful, apart from being mathematically interesting?

Comment: @dsp_user, It is inherently useful as a mathematical description of the behavior of a pure tone in a DFT.  This is the point of the "Qualitative Analysis" section.  The bin value equations make the bin value a function of the frequency, amplitude, and phase, as you state.  The advantage of the simple form I found is that it is invertible.  In other words, you can find its inverse function which gives frequency, amplitude, and phase as a function of bin values.  The frequency inverse is robust, the other two are not.  See my other blog articles for details.

Answer (score 5):

MATLAB uses one based indexing, DFTs are zero based, so you have to shift your index value by one.

The bin index corresponds to the the frequency in units of cycles per frame.  Your `freq` is in units of cycles per second.  The sample count is in units of samples per frame and the sampling rate is units of samples per second. The bin index calculation should be:

\begin{align}
\mathrm{bin} &= \mathrm{freq} \cdot \frac{N}{f_s}\\
15 &= 10 \cdot \frac{1500}{1000}
\end{align}

Where the units are:

$$\rm \frac{cycles}{frame} = \frac{cycles}{second} \cdot \frac{\displaystyle\frac{samples}{frame}}{\displaystyle\frac{samples}{second}} $$

Bin 15 is in index 16 of MATLAB.  Since this is a whole number of cycles per frame, all your other bin values should be zero.

Hope this helps.

Ced

---

Follow up

Your calculation should have been:

$$\rm \frac{Frequency\ Bin \times Sampling\ Frequency}{Number\ of\ Samples} = \frac{15 \times 1000}{1500} = 10$$

Bin $-15$, aka bin $1485$, will also be non-zero and the complex conjugate of bin $15$.  Each should have a magnitude of $2.5$.  Your DC bin, aka bin $0$, should have a value of $-6$.  The corresponding MATLAB indexes will be $16$, $1486$, and $1$.